# How to make a variable visible between functions

Tags: php, function, variables

I would make a variable visible from different functions without using parameters, e.g. like making public a variable. Is this possible in php?
This is a simple example of what I would like do:

```
<?php
    calc();

    function a(){
        $var=1; // I would make $var visible to function calc()
    }

    function calc(){
        a();
        $var2=3/$var;
        echo $var2;
    }
?>
```

Comment: Give it a few minutes: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php

Comment: But in case the function a() must return a lot of variables and I will not use arrays..

Comment: Why don't you want to use arrays? Using lots of global variables is very poor design.

Comment: @Barmar , I'm doing a porting from C# to PHP, and if I do as you have rightly suggested I should change name to all variables

Comment: learn about global variables and scope

Comment: How did the job of porting to PHP get assigned to someone who doesn't know the basics of PHP variables?

Comment: I know the basics of php... I don't know for example that global variables may be declared in a function and not outside.

Answer (score 2):

It can use a global variable, but it is in most cases WRONG WAY!

```
function a(){
    global $var=1; // as well as in the second function
}
```

Better to go back through the variable return

```
function a(){
    return 1;
}

function calc(){
    $var = a();
    $var2=3/$var;
    echo $var2;
}
```

Or use OOP/class

```
class Calculator {
  var $var;
  function a(){
    $this->var=1; // I would make $var visible to function calc()
  }

  function calc(){
    $this->a();
    $var2=3/$this->var;
    echo $var2;
  }
}

$calculator = new Calculator();
$calculator->calc();
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments by Rizier123 and aldrin27, you just need to return the value in `a()`:

```
calc();

function a(){
    $var = 1;
    return $var;
}

function calc(){
    $var = a();
    $var2 = 3 / $var;
    echo $var2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can't return the values, you can use `global`.

```
function a() {
    global $var;
    $var = 1;
}

function calc() {
    global $var;
    $var2 = 3/$var;
    echo $var2;
}
```